# How to get thread context? (ctypes - "WindowsError: [Error 126]")

Tags: python, ctypes

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.windll.context()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Program Files\python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 435, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
  File "D:\Program Files\python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126]
```

And

```
ctypes.windll.wow64_context()
```

Same output...

What is this error message telling me?

Comment: I hate to be bringer of bad news, but if you can not figure out what's wrong here you have 0% chance to actually properly implement a `GetThreadContext` using `ctypes`. It's a reasonably complicated process that requires a lot of knowledge.

Comment: Learn at least the basics of x86 and x86-64 CPU architecture -- such as the register names and how they're normally used. Get comfortable reading C/C++ to learn by example. Read the ctypes tutorial. Learn about the rights rights requested and granted (e.g. `THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME`, `THREAD_GET_CONTEXT`) when opening a handle to a Windows object, and how that relates to the object's security descriptor and your thread's access token (SIDs and enabled privileges).

Comment: @orlp A person has to start somewhere.  That's a pretty vile error message: if someone knows what it means, why don't they just answer?

Comment: @GreenAsJade Because they'll get stuck on literally the very next hurdle, getting nowhere.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, but I can image that having an answer in our programming questions database (StackOverflow) about what does Error 126 mean in the context of ctypes would be a useful thing.

Comment: @GreenAsJade, if someone can't figure out what [Error 126](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382#ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND) is and what [`ctypes.windll`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.LibraryLoader) is, then getting a thread `CONTEXT` is too difficult.